# How can i run my GPS application in background?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to send my current location to php web service after every 5 min even if my application is runing in background. I try to make this thing but its working good when my application in running state but when i put this application in background it stop sending data so please any buddy tell how can i run my application in background.

Answer (score 8):

By "running in background", do you mean running when under the lock screen? If this is the case, then you need to set `PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;`

The post [Running a Windows Phone Application under the lock screen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/01/running-a-windows-phone-application-under-the-lock-screen.aspx) by Jaime Rodriguez covers the subject well.

However, if you're talking about running an application that continues to run while the user uses other applications on the device, then this is not possible. In the Mango build of the operating system you can create background agents, but these only run every 30 minutes and only for 15 seconds as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

There is a request on the official UserVoice forum for Windows Phone development to [Provide an agent to track routes](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1720113-provide-an-agent-to-track-routes-), but even if adopted, this would not be available for quite some time.

Comment: As said, in mango, you can access location services from a background task but the location is cached and only updated every 15 mins.

Comment: And the RTM of Mango supports ResourceIntensiveTask which looks promising but turns out to be useless.

Answer (score 4):

Tracking applications are the bulk of what I do for a living, and the prospect of using WP7 like this is the primary reason I acquired one.

From a power consumption perspective, transmitting data is the single most expensive thing you can do, followed closely by sampling the GPS and accelerometers.

To produce a trace that closely conforms to roads, you need a higher sampling rate. WP7 won't let you sample more than once per second. This is (just barely) fast enough to track a motor vehicle, and at this level of power consumption the battery will last for about an hour *assuming you log the data on the phone and don't attempt to transmit it*.

You will also find that if you transmit for every sample, your sampling interval will be at least 15 seconds. Running the web call on another thread won't help because it will take more than one second to complete and you will run out of sockets in less than a minute with a one second sample interval.

There are solutions to all of these problems. For example, in a motor vehicle you can connect to vehicle power and run hot. You can batch and burst your data on a background thread.

These, however, are only the basic problems faced by every tracker designer. More interesting are the questions of proximity in space and time, measurement of deviation from a route, how to specify routes and geofences in a time dependent manner, how to associate them into named sets for rule evaluation purposes and how to associate rules with named sets of routes and geofences.

And then there is periodic clustering, which introduces all the calendrical nightmares that are too much for your average developer of desktop software. To apply the speed limit for a school zone you need to know the time zone, daylight savings, two start and two stop times and the start and end dates for school holidays in that region.

If you are just doing this for fun or as some kind of hiking trace then a five minute interval will impose much milder power demands than one second sampling, but I still suggest batch and burst because it means you can track locations that don't have comms.